# How to create new matrix base on combination of two columns from a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I am trying to figure out a way to create a new matrix base on combination of two columns.

```
df <- data.frame(a=100:120, b=90:110, c=95:115, d=letters[1:21])
```

For example,
I want a combination of  a and d, b and d, c and d.
if value in a is less than 110 and value in d is in a to d, i want to create a new column a1 and assign the value as 0.003. If d is in e to f, I want to assign 0.005 etc. If want to do the same for each combination. So, the resulting matrix would be 20 x 3. I tried mapply like this

```
func <- function(a, d){
    if(a >= 110 & d %in% c("a","b","c","d")
    {
        y <- 0.003
    }
  else if(a >= 110 & d %in% c("e","f")){
    y <- 0.005
  }
  else{
    y <- 1
  }
}

g <- mapply(func , df, df$d)
```

It returns a vector with 20 elements in it. I am expecting 20 x 3 matrix. Which apply function should I use? Thanks.

Comment: what are the three columns you are expecting? The function would only return 20 values of y (if it works).

Comment: I am expecting 20 rows and 3 columns with values such as 0.003, 0.005 or 1 depending on whether they meet the if else condition.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. My understanding is that you would like to make (k-1) combinations, where k is the number of columns, of each column in the data frame with the last element, run the function you defined above against the columns of a certain combination, and store the result in a column. The result should be n by (k-1):

```
df <- data.frame(a=100:120, b=90:110, c=95:115, d=letters[1:21]) 

func <- function(a, d){
  if(a >= 110 & d %in% c("a","b","c","d"))
     {
       y <- 0.003
  }
  else if(a >= 110 & d %in% c("e","f")){
    y <- 0.005
  }
  else{
    y <- 1
  }
}

result.df = data.frame();
for(i in  1:(length(df) - 1)) { #assuming that d is the last element always
  g <- mapply(func , df[[i]], df[[length(df)]]);
  if(length(result.df) == 0) {
    result.df = as.data.frame(g)
  } else {
    result.df = cbind(result.df, as.data.frame(g))
  }
  colnames(result.df)[i] = i;
} 

result.matrix = as.matrix(result.df) #if you want the result as a matrix
```

Comment: That works. Thanks. Is there a way to achieve it without a loop?

Comment: Could you please share with me your design goal? Why no loop?